# Select query in SQL SERVER need to support

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 3 tables like that:

```
- Employee_Table (Employee_Number, Employee_Name, Department_Number) 
    With Employee_Number is PRIMARY KEY, Department_Number is FOREIGN KEY;

- Employee_Skill_Table (Employee_Number, Skill_Code, Date Registered) 
    With PRIMARY KEY (Employee_Number, Skill_Code);

- Department (Department_Number, Department_Name) 
    With PRIMARY KEY (Department_Number);
```

How can I specify

`the departments which have >= 3 employees`

Help me!

Comment: Hint : `group by Department_Number having count(*) >=3` with a proper join

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I tried but it error with Group by clause when I join Employee_Table and Department

Comment: Oh it works!!! Thank you so much @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the departments that have more than 3 people try this query

```
SELECT d.Department_Name
FROM Department d 
JOIN Employee_Table e ON e.Department_Number = d.Department_Number
GROUP BY Department_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dept.department_name 
FROM employee_table emp 
INNER JOIN department dept ON emp.department_number= dept.department_number 
GROUP BY emp.department_number 
HAVING COUNT(emp.department_number) >= 3
```